# How to subset a local macro in Stata

Tags: stata

Suppose I have a local macro containing some variable names

```
local indep "cat dog pig"
```

How do I drop `pig` from the macro, if I want the macro to contain only `cat` and `dog`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The context is that you want to remove variable names from a string listing them. The `subinstr()` solution in the OP's answer works only if the text to remove occurs just once as an entire variable name, and does not occur as part of another variable name. Thus the result of removing `pig` from this list with equivalent but not identical syntax is

```
. local names "cat dog pig piglet"

. local names : subinstr local names "pig" "", all

. di "`names'"
cat dog  let
```

That is not what you want. The solution is to insist that what is removed must be a word. In Stata, words are or could be separated by spaces (other than being bound by double quotes); in the case of Stata variable names, distinct variable names are always distinct words.

```
. local names "cat dog pig piglet"

. local names : subinstr local names "pig" "", word

. di "`names'"
cat dog  piglet
```

When handling lists of variable names, Stata doesn't care about multiple spaces rather than single spaces, so neither need you. But if they offend, they can be reduced to single spaces.

See also the functions `subinstr()` and `subinword()` for approaches similar in spirit. In some older versions of Stata there were rather strict limits on string length for such functions, which made use of the construct used above `: subinstr` advisable for all but very short lists.

Here, however, is a quite different solution:

```
. local names "cat dog pig piglet"

. local pig "pig"

. local names : list names - pig

. di "`names'"
cat dog piglet
```

In a program, that is often much better, especially if you want to remove several names (more generally "words") at once.

Comment: Nick is not explicit about it, but I'll mention it, since some users are not aware of the constructs in use: _macro extended functions_; and the help can be found directly with `help extended_fcn`. A link can also be found within `help macro`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I have found the answer myself..

```
local indep "cat dog pig"
local indep = subinstr("`indep'", "pig", "", .)
local indep = rtrim("`indep'")
```

but I am not sure if this is a good answer. This works only if `pig` comes last in the macro.

Comment: Not so. The  text `pig` will be removed wherever it occurs. If there is a difference it's only in terms of what spaces are left. `trim(itrim())` will clean up. The bigger problem is if you have `cat dog pig piglet` and want to remove `pig` but not `piglet`. See my answer.